# Simulating a communication system in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, simulink

i am trying to plot the theoretical and the simulated BER curves using BERtool of this communication system : 
[image]

The simulated curve is a constant horizontal line all over the range and therefore it is not even comparable to the theoretical one. The system modulation scheme is 8-psk ,so any suggestions ?

Comment: Any suggestions guys ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you should specify receive delay in “Error Rate Calculation” block. Delay for default settings is 34.

Best Wishes, IB.